# browser login mask in adMob banner

Tags: android, http, admob

i have adMob in my app.. I noticed strange behavior. If I connected to wifi network, that requires login via browser, than I see this login mask(or a part of this login page) in the admob banner in my android app. How is it possible? I expect that admob do a http request to goole  and displays content only if request is successful. And it should not be a login mask! :)

here a banner definition:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMob"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ID" />
```

and here my code:

```
adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adMob);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });
```

Comment: are you using proper id to this ads:adUnitId

Comment: I think yes, I see normal admon banner after login to the network. Or if am using mobile network like umts, where no browser login is required. And I get clicks and money for my admob account.. so its seems to be ok.. only that strange behavior with a login mask, which I do not understand :)

Comment: are you sure about using id for admob like this  adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a9876sf98dfg"); just follow this https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Comment: no, because I declare it in xml. And its not the best way with defining new instance in the code, because than your banner overlap your layout. So Im using this: 
adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adMob);

Comment: have you declared proper attributes in the res folder

Comment: could you please specify what attributes are you meaning?